# Get 2 counters from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following structure of documents in my table:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const logSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    eventName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['connect', 'status', 'probability'],
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const Log = mongoose.model('Log', logSchema);

module.exports = Log;
```

My intention is to extract an array of size `7` (7 past days - past week). Each item is a JSON with 2 primary fields: counter for start and for end. I want to count how many documents in `0<=i<=7`th day are considered as start and how many as end.

Consider document as start if `eventName === 'connect` and consider it end otherwise.

This my current code, which counts how many documents are in each day generally (both start and end). But I'd like to change it to get how many, in each day, considered as start and how many as end. How can I do it?

```
weeklyLogs = await Log.aggregate([
    { $match: { timestamp: { $gte: moment.tz('Asia/Jerusalem').subtract(6, 'days').startOf('day').toDate() } } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $dateFromParts: {
                    year: { $year: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                    month: { $month: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                    day: { $dayOfMonth: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                    timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem"
                }
            },
            documents: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { $project: { documents: 1 } }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1

Adding conditions to `$sum`:

```
weeklyLogs = await Log.aggregate([
  { $match: { timestamp: { $gte: moment.tz('Asia/Jerusalem').subtract(6, 'days').startOf('day').toDate() } } },
  {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $dateFromParts: {
                year: { $year: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                month: { $month: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem"
            }
        },
        start: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: ['$eventName', 'connect'] }, 1, 0]
            }
        },
        end: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $ne: ['$eventName', 'connect'] }, 1, 0]
            }
        }
    }
  }
]);
```

### Method 2

You can use `$facet` to process multiple aggregation pipelines like this:

```
weeklyLogs = await Log.aggregate([
  { $match: { timestamp: { $gte: moment.tz('Asia/Jerusalem').subtract(6, 'days').startOf('day').toDate() } } },
  {
    $facet: {
        start:  [
            { $match: { eventName: 'connect' } },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        $dateFromParts: {
                            year: { $year: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                            month: { $month: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                            day: { $dayOfMonth: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                            timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem"
                        }
                    },
                    documents: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            }
        ],
        end: [
            { $match: { eventName: { $ne: 'connect' } } },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        $dateFromParts: {
                            year: { $year: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                            month: { $month: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                            day: { $dayOfMonth: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem" } },
                            timezone: "Asia/Jerusalem"
                        }
                    },
                    documents: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Right now the `_id` fields appears inside both start and end. Is there a way to move it outside? So the json would look like `{ _id: ...., start: ....., end: ....}`? Edit: NVM, the first method is what I need , thanks.

Comment: Check method 1, it should have the output you need